# error Element is not clickable at point (183, 798) web scraping python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping, clickable

I am new using python and I have a problem. I am trying to create a loop of web scraping for getting information, but my loop requires two clicks.
the page that I am using is: https://www.becual.com/oportunidades
and for each inversion opportunity I need to click and then get the information "credito solicitado" and "empresa pagadora". This is the code that I use for the loop.

```
firmas = []
for i in range(0, size):
    detalles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 imagen-oportunidad"]')
    detalles[i].click()
    time.sleep(3)
    monto = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span:nth-last-child(3)').text
    garantia = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div[2]/becual-opportunity-detail/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a')
    garantia.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    empresa = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[2]/becual-opportunity-detail/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/strong").text
    browser.back()
    time.sleep(10)
    firmas.append({'Monto': monto, 'Empresa': empresa})
```

my loop works until number 3. But then it says that it isn´t clickable.
I click only the third element and the click works using the xpath written in mi loop code ('//div[@class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 imagen-oportunidad"]'). I don´t understand why with the loop doesnt work but doing it alone it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requests` to load the data from external API:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = ' https://api.becual.com/api/oportunidad?incluirHistorico=false&page=1&limit=10000'
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for data in data['data']:
    o = requests.get('https://api.becual.com/api/oportunidad/' + data['idOportunidad']).json()
    # uncomment to print all data about opportunity:
    # print(json.dumps(o, indent=4))
    nombre = o['garantias'][0]['nombreEmpresa'] if o['garantias'] else '-'
    print('{:<15} {:<15} {}'.format(o['idOportunidad'], o['montoCredito'], nombre))
```

Prints:

```
CR1808213969    16000000        Altamira Chile
CR1712292810    10400000        Jej Ingeniería
CR1712202756    4800000         Soc. Agricola Requingua
CR1712052601    15583739        Soc. Agricola Requingua
CR1801042850    7200000         International Paper Cartones
CR1809144426    707264          CONSTRUCTORA METROPOLITANA S.A.
CR1710102345    3500000         Soc. Agricola Requingua
CR1712262781    8700000         Compañía Industrial el Volcán
CR1711072497    4200000         Viña Santa Ema
CR1709272302    8100000         Soc. Agricola Requingua
CR1712272789    10400000        Jej Ingeniería
CR1802023015    11100000        SGS Chile
CR1801182911    5500000         Soc. Agricola Requingua
CR1711022486    6100000         International Paper Cartones
CR1711102516    8723983         International Paper Cartones

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Element is not loaded properly in DOM and not in state to accept click. Try below code with wait for element be clickable

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 imagen-oportunidad"]')))

element.click();
```